# Split c() inside of a string vector

Tags: r

I am working with a vector of strings in r. However, when I see the first item in the list I see this:

```
> uni_list[1]

[1] c("ENSMUSG00000000204", "ENSMUSG00000115878", "ENSMUSG00000116453", "ENSMUSG00000116134")
15940 Levels: c("ENSMUSG00000000204", "ENSMUSG00000115878", "ENSMUSG00000116453", "ENSMUSG00000116134")
```

How can I split this one in separate values?

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: Maybe try: `unlist(uni_list)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`, i.e.

```
split(l3[[1]], seq(length(l3[[1]])))
$`1`
[1] "ENSMUSG00000000204"

$`2`
[1] "ENSMUSG00000115878"

$`3`
[1] "ENSMUSG00000116453"

$`4`
[1] "ENSMUSG00000116134"
```

where

```
l3
[[1]]
[1] "ENSMUSG00000000204" "ENSMUSG00000115878" "ENSMUSG00000116453" "ENSMUSG00000116134"
```